# How to make a Link that will open an Infopath form in the Client application

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath, csom

The library advanced settings is already set to "open in client applicaton".  But when I add a link to the form to the Sharepoint page, it still tries to open as a browser-enabled form, generating an error.  -  [Correlation ID:84451e9f-70f7-a000-98f1-5074e6e0f3e2]

I.E.  I wish to create a link that functions like [+New]->[Form] in the library view command bar.

Answer (score 0):

You use the Promoted Link app in SharePoint

check out this link : https://sharepoint.rackspace.com/sharepoint-2013-how-to-create-a-promoted-links-list-app-part-1

Answer (score 0):

How did you add a link to the form to the SharePoint page?

Whether you publish the InfoPath form to a Form library? If I just publish the InfoPath to a Form library, it will open the form in the client application when I click +New->Form in the library.

Have you installed the InfoPath client on the local? Try to use another browser and check again.

Try to go to FILE tab in InfoPath Desiger->Form Options-> Compatibility, change the Form type to "InfoPath Filler Form" and check again.

Comment: Thanks for your answers!  I will try the promoted links tonight.

Comment: I should have provided a little more detail...  I need to hide the library command bars to prevent users from deleting forms outside infopath. So I tried just creating a link on the SharePoint page to the form template. But even with the library set to client application the link always tries to open in the browser...