# Can a Sharepoint site admin (not server admin) Change what options are available on a library Command Bar?

Tags: sharepoint-online, infopath

My (non-browser-enabled) Infopath form functionality requires users to have write access to the library (to save changes to previously submitted form data).

BUT - I do not want to users to see the [Upload], [Delete]. etc. buttons on the Command bar.  (Because, as you now, if they are there, they will use them...)

AND I cannot just mute display of the Command bar because, as yet, I cannot find a way for users to open to a non-browser-enabled form, except for the [New] button on the Command bar. re:[How to make a Link that will open an Infopath form in the Client application](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/273092/how-to-make-a-link-that-will-open-an-infopath-form-in-the-client-application)

Answer (score 0):

There is no OOB solution to hide Command Bar button in SharePoint Online. 
You might want to consider [SPFx Application Customizer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/using-page-placeholder-with-extensions) to apply customization on modern UI.

On the other hand, it is possible to organize InfoPath forms outside of SharePoint and still be able to send data to lists or libraries.

Please see the links below.

[Submit form data to a SharePoint library.](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/submit-form-data-to-a-sharepoint-library-86e3c32d-d921-4b2e-9d74-89bdc62c6936)

[Submitting to a SharePoint List.](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2007/03/26/submitting-to-a-sharepoint-list/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer!  I do already use the submit functionality. I had not considered just storing the forms in a network location and maybe using excel or access instead of library views...  That would be a procedural change for my users but might be more efficient as the corporation has hamstrung our SharePoint implementation anyway...  I will have to seriously think on that!